# Website Treating me as mobile when scraping from html in python

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am attempting to scrape data off of a website using a combination of urllib2 and beautifulsoup. At the moment, here is my code:

```
site2='http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/archive/nfl/2008/619811/draftresults'
players=[]
teams=[]
response=urllib2.urlopen(site2)
html=response.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
playername = soup.find_all('a', class_="name")
teamname = soup.find_all('td', class_="last")
```

My problem is, that when I view the source code in Chrome, these tags are readily available and working, but when I try and run the program, the tags are no longer there.

One hint may be that the first line of the source code reads like such:
   `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">` 
While if I print my soup or html object the first line is `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">`.
It appears that the url appears in a mobile form when I try and scrape it using urllib2. If this is not what this means, or you do in fact know how to have urllib2 open the url as a browser (preferably chrome) would, please let me know! Please also be quite specific as to how I can solve the problem, as I am a novice coder and admittedly my depth of knowledge is shallow at best!

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website tries to figure out what browser the source of the request is from the 'User-agent'. According to the urllib2 [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request), the default user-agent is `Python-urllib/2.6`. You could try setting that to that of a browser using OpenerDirector. Again, from the docs:

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
opener.open('http://www.example.com/')
```